# Kendo Grid not sorting data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have made grid as below:

```
$("#gvObservationScore").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: Data,
                columns: [{
                    title: "Code",
                    width: 4,
                    template: "#= getCodeForScoreGrid(TitleCode,componentCode)#"
                }, {
                    field: "CorrelatedTo",
                    title: "CorrelatedTo",
                    width: 30,
                    template: "#= getCorrelationTextForScoreGrid(correlatedTo,CorrScoreID)#"
                }
                , {
                    field: "Score",
                    title: "Score",
                    width: 5,
                    template: "#= getScoreTextForScoreGrid(correlationScore,correlatedTo,CorrScoreID)#"
                }
                , {
                    field: "NS",
                    title: "NS",
                    width: 3,
                    template: "#= getNSRadioButtonForScoreGrid(correlationScore,correlatedTo,CorrScoreID,CorrID,componentCode)#"
                }


                     , {
                         field: "1",
                         title: "1",
                         width: 3,
                         template: "#= getOneScoreRadioButtonForScoreGrid(correlationScore, correlatedTo, CorrScoreID, CorrID, componentCode)#"
                     }
                     , {
                         field: "2",
                         title: "2",
                         width: 3,
                         template: "#= getTwoScoreRadioButtonForScoreGrid(correlationScore, correlatedTo, CorrScoreID, CorrID, componentCode)#"
                     }
                     , {
                         field: "3",
                         title: "3",
                         width: 3,
                         template: "#= getThreeScoreRadioButtonForScoreGrid(correlationScore, correlatedTo, CorrScoreID, CorrID, componentCode)#"
                     }
                     , {
                         field: "4",
                         title: "4",
                         width: 3,
                         template: "#= getFourScoreRadioButtonForScoreGrid(correlationScore, correlatedTo, CorrScoreID, CorrID, componentCode)#"
                     }
                     , {
                         field: "AddComment",
                         title: "Add Comment",
                         width: 10,
                         template: "#= getAddCommentButtonForScoreGrid(componentCode,CorrScoreID,CorrID,commentCount) #"
                     }
                     //getThreeScoreRadioButtonForScoreGrid
                ],
                sortable: true

            });
```

It looks as follows:

[image]

But grid is not getting sorted.

I have already kept `sortable:true` in my code.

**Also tried with :**

```
sortable: {
                mode: "single",
                allowUnsort: false
            }
```

Then also not getting sorted.

Please help me.

Comment: What exactly is the expected sort result? The pic shows sort by "CorrelatedTo", looks right to me unless if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$("#gvObservationScore").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: Data,
                sortable: true,
                columns: [{
                    title: "Code",
                    width: 4,
                    sortable: true,
                    template: "#= getCodeForScoreGrid(TitleCode,componentCode)#"
                }, {
                    field: "CorrelatedTo",
                    title: "CorrelatedTo",
                    width: 30,
                    template: "#= getCorrelationTextForScoreGrid(correlatedTo,CorrScoreID)#"
                }
                ................
```

I have added **sortable** to the **grid**, and a **column** as an example

**EDIT**:

Since all are templates, you might be missing the escape characters before the `#` tags i.e.

```
template: "//#= getCodeForScoreGrid(TitleCode,componentCode)//#"
```

Comment: no not getting errors but data is not getting sorted

Comment: can you post the data and the code for the template `getCodeForScoreGrid`?  I suspect the template is generating code which isn't sortable

Comment: function getCodeForScoreGrid(TitleCode, componentCode) {
        return false;" style="text-decoration: none;">' + compText + '</a>';
       
       
    }